# Why raising an exception isn't limited to exception class?

Tags: delphi, exception

This delphi code is compilable and works as expected.

```
program RaiseLabel;

uses FastMM4, Windows, StdCtrls;

function CreateLabel(const S: string): TLabel;
begin
  Result := TLabel.Create(nil);
  Result.Caption := S;
end;

begin
  try
    raise CreateLabel('Strange exception example');
  except
    on L: TLabel do begin
      MessageBox(0, PChar(L.Caption), 'TLabel', MB_OK);
    end;
  end;
end.
```

My question is that why exception handling isn't limited to raise an exception object that is a descendant of class Exception. (I used FastMM in full debug mode to test if this program causes any memory leak - it doesn't.)

Comment: `SysUtils.Exception` is provided as a *convenience*, not a *requirement*. Just like C++ exceptions are not *required* to be based on `std::exception`. In both languages, you can `raise`/`throw` just about anything you want. It doesn't even have to be object-based

Comment: Let this be the one and only time you `raise` something that does not descend from `Exception`

Comment: @David: I faced this when I was fighting against exceptions leaking from a third-party dll that was compiled with a different version of Delphi or BCB. The leaking exception was catched by the 'finally' block in my code, because the 'on E: Exception' block didn't recognize it as exception. I tried to simulate the situation and ended up with this conclusion.

Comment: @malom `on E: Exception` relies on RTTI to match the raised exception to the `Exception` class. RTTI is different between versions of the compiler. Unless you need access to `E`, you can omit the `on` clause and just use `except` by itself. On the other hand, DLLs are not supposed to let exceptions cross the DLL boundary into the calling executable to begin with, so you should file a bug report with the DLL vendor

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I already created wrapper functions that catch exceptions as you described above using AcquireExceptionObject(). The object as a pointer can be casted to a pointer to a record that corresponds to a Delphi7 exception object's fields. My question was only that